# Editing button properties from a module

Tags: vb.net, button

I am just starting out with Visual basic .Net.

I can't seem to figure what's the scope of button properties like button.text. Can they be used outside the button_click event sub? And if so, how?

How can I modify button properties from a module in real time when a certain condition is met?

I'd surely appreciate some guidance and an example, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: that doesn't look like a good idea. Can I ask why you need to do that from a Module? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just out of plain curiosity. I will separate it in the form if it's not possible to refer them from the module.

Comment: yes you can change properties from modules, classes or other forms.  the code there needs to have a valid reference to the form or control though.  Its generally a bad idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as quick sample, I don't suggest doing something like this

I have 2 forms open, `Form2` and `Form3`. Each form has a button on it.

I also have a `Module`, called **MyModule**

```
Public Class Form2

    Public Sub ChangeButtonText(ByVal s As String)

        Button1.Text = s

    End Sub

End Class
```

.

```
Public Module MyModule

    Sub ChangeForm2Btn()
        Form2.ChangeButtonText("LOL")
    End Sub

End Module
```

From my Form3 I click the button and call the module function to change `Form2` button's text

```
Public Class Form3

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MyModule.ChangeForm2Btn()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference to the button to a sub in the module, and then call that sub from the form.

i.e.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ChangeButtonText(Me.Button1, "Changed")

    End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
Module modButton

    Public Sub ChangeButtonText(ByRef Button As Button, ByVal Text As String)

        Button.Text = Text

    End Sub

End Module
```